# 3-address instruction is too large to fit in one word for a reasonable word length

Tags: cpu-architecture

[image: word length]
Can someone explain the paragraph given in the picture? I also have trouble understanding the address space and word length. Can you explain the relation between them? Thank you.

Comment: What parts don't you understand, or, if it is easier, what parts *do* you understand?

Comment: @scott Hunter I do not understand the 3-address instruction not fitting in a word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory operands need some bits to specify addressing mode, base register, and offset.

If you don't have any registers (so your operands are always absolute memory addresses), then addresses need to be *large* to be useful; e.g. 16-bit offsets can only address 64kiB of memory, and two 16-bit addresses would take up an entire 32-bit instruction word, let alone 3.

Memory machines without registers are garbage for performance, even with fast cache, so they're not very interesting anyway.  There's a reason that essentially every microprocessor in real use has at least an accumulator, and usually some kind of pointer register.  Forcing every result to be stored back into memory and then reloaded again would increase latency a lot.